# How to check type of a JSON object against typescript interface in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a result JSON object being passed onto a function which I would need to check the type of it against a Typescript interface definition model, in order to be perform specific rendering changes prior displaying it.

I am facing an issue, where the string matches all the interface types as it goes through the checks, using (jsonResult as TypeScriptInterfaceName) and simply doesnt deliver the correct value subsequently.

I tried the class transformer library as well with no luck. Whats the best way to explicitly check and fail the string against the typescript definition.

Thank you.

```
interface ParentOne {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    child: Child
}
interface Child {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}
**JSON ONE**
{
    id: value,
    title: value,
    child: [{}],
}


interface ParentTwo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    directory: Directory
}
interface Directory {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}

**JSON TWO**
{
    id: value,
    title: value,
    directory: [{}],
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample JSON data, the Type interface, and the error message?

Comment: @codingwithmanny I am trying to simply using the following approach: if (JSON ONE as ParentOne) { do something } else if (JSON TWO as ParentTwo) { do another }

Comment: JSON is a string, so checking the type would be meaningless. If you mean checking the parsed JSON, then you're talking about a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Comment: You do not have the types at runtime so you cannot check against them at runtime.

Comment: @HereticMonkey correct, bad wording, javascript object derived from a json string.

Comment: @Victory Thanks for the tip. So what would be the best way to handle a situation like this. Append a flag to the object prior to passing and checking it that way or is there a neater solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

When you're parsing JSON the resulting type will be `any`. Type information doesn't exist at runtime, so Typescript can't help you there.

What we do is create a JSON-Schema file that describes the JSON file, and then we use a JSON-Schema validator like `ajv` to validate if the incoming JSON object matches the schema.

We then use a tool like `json-schema-to-typescript` to generate types based on the schemas.

Our validation function finally looks something like this:

```js
function validateBody<T>(body: unknown, jsonSchemaId: string): asserts body is T {

   // Do validation or throw error

}
```

This means that from a single JSON-Schema, we get:

1. Typescript types in the backend
2. Typescript types in the frontend
3. Documentation
4. A server-side validator with useful errors.
5. Type-safety (after validation)

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't have the interface definitions at runtime you can't count on them for sanity checking, what you might do is something like the following.

#### Given some useful interfaces

```
interface ParentOne {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    child: Child
}
interface Child {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}

interface ParentTwo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    directory: Directory
}
interface Directory {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}
```

#### We want a way to use those nice interfaces

```
const processParentOne = (p: ParentOne) => {
  console.log(p.child);
}

const processParentTwo = (p: ParentTwo) => {
  console.log(p.directory);
}
```

#### So we cast them as soon as we can infer the type

```
const processionJson = (data: any) => {
  if (!!data.child) {
    processParentOne(data as ParentOne);
  } else if(!!data.directory) {
    processParentTwo(data as ParentTwo);
  }
}
```

#### So that we can do something like

```
const p1: ParentOne = {
  id: 'po',
  title: "p1",
  child: {
    id: 'chopo',
    title: 'little'
  }
}

const p2: ParentTwo = {
  id: 'pt',
  title: 'p2',
  directory: {
    id: 'dirpt',
    title: 'dict'
  }
}

// Remove all the type info for example
const json = (Math.random() < .5) 
  ? JSON.stringify(p1) : JSON.stringify(p2);

// pass along "unknown" data type
processionJson(JSON.parse(json))
```

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation, much appreciated!

Comment: @sam if this helped you can upvote and mark as answered.